# Getting value with null when trying to combining orderByChild() and startAt()

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Getting Value as null when trying below code for sorting and filtering data using orderByChild() and startAt()**

I'm Attaching image below for data structure and result which I am getting in form of data snapshots.

[image]
[image]

Code as Follows

```
Query queryMeal = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("meals");
            queryMeal.orderByChild("meal_name").startAt("ggh").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Log.e("Query DataSnapShot",""+dataSnapshot.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: the result is obvious brother as you are trying to query  'meal_name' which is 3 level down but for using orderByChild the child must be 2 level down

Comment: at this moment your code is returning results from the one level up from the node you are expecting it to return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
Query queryMeal = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("meals");
ueryMeal.orderByChild("meal_name").startAt("ggh").addListenerForSingleValueEvent();
```

to

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
Query queryMeal = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("meals").child(uid);
ueryMeal.orderByChild("meal_name").startAt("ggh").endAt("ggh" + "\uf8ff").addListenerForSingleValueEvent();
```

**Edit:**

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mealsRef = rootRef.child("meals");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot uidSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String uid = uidSnapshot.getKey();

            DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("meals").child(uid).startAt("ggh").endAt("ggh" + "\uf8ff");
            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String mealName = ds.child("meal_name").getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d(TAG, mealName);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
                }
            };
            uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
mealsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: Boss these looks good but i want to search in whole "meal" node.

Comment: In this case, you should query your database twice, as in my updated answer, right?

Comment: Thank you boss it helps with some modification.

Comment: @HimanshuBhoraniya You're welcome! Do you think that my answer helped you?

Comment: Yes buddy it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your onDataChange Method do something like this

```
if(dataSnapshot != null){
   Log.e("Query DataSnapShot",""+dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
}
```